# $F\subset B \subset E$ are fields . If $[E:F]$ is finite so must be $[E:B]$ and $[B:F]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$F\subset B \subset E$  are fields  and $[E:F]$   is  finite .  Then   to  prove  that  $[E:B]$  and  $[B:F]$  are  both  finite  and  $[E:F]=[E:B].[B:F]$

Please  give me  some  hints  as  to  how  to  begin the  thinking .  I  am  really  stuck .

Comment: HINT: Assume that one of them is not finite and try to come to a contradiction

Answer (score 1):

Think about $E/F$, $E/B$, and $B/F$ as vector spaces. First show that $[E:B]<\infty$ and $[B:F] < \infty$, and then consider bases of $E/B$ and $B/F$ to get a basis for $E/F$. Doing this will give you the relation $[E:F] = [E:B][B:F]$.